# Change # of decimal places with Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to change # of decimal places of all cells in Google Sheets with app script? I'm trying to create a dropdown button in Google Sheets where the user can select the # of decimal places to display in current worksheet. I've checked the app script documentation but didn't find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 6):

.toFixed() Method may help your work.

var x = 9.656;

x.toFixed(2);

[Number Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_number_tofixed)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a Google Sheets formula to allow for this. There are also not GAS specific methods to perform the function as far as I have seen. There are, however, some universal JavaScript methods to mimic this.

You can find the documentation for the `.toFixed()` method [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp). This method changes a number to a string with the specified decimal places. This will change the output format so be aware of the type of data you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setNumberFormat()` function within the Range object.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setNumberFormat("0.00")
```